# Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint error on AWS Lambda Custom Runtime

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created an AWS Lambda function using Lambda Custom Runtime on Amazon Linux 2 which generates an example that, if I execute the example, it fails with permission denied error:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: f6adb86a-7fbd-4ed5-85d8-2e07edda78e6 Error: fork/exec /var/task/bootstrap: permission denied",
  "errorType": "Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint"
}
```

I am trying to use custom runtime to run a bash script in Lambda. Anyone know how I can fix this permission issue?

Comment: The error is self evident. There is a permission issue due to which the lambda is not executed. Fix the file permission issue and try again,

Comment: chmod +x filename

Comment: This is rather frustrating as the example custom bootstrap from AWS themselves provides files with incorrect permissions. In order to fix you need to download the files, update permissions and re upload the same files for the example to even work

Answer (score 1):

This is rather frustrating as the example custom bootstrap from AWS themselves provides files with incorrect permissions. In order to fix you need to download the files, update permissions and re upload the same files for the example to even work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What are the incorrect and correct permissions?